# MultipartUploadRequest (Error during upload) android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-upload

I have used this in multiple projects never got any error but when i tried this in android 10 its attempt to upload but after some time it gives error during upload. If there is any one who

tried this way as well:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`

`My code:

```
 try{
  String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        Toast.makeText(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Creating a multi part request


        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                .setMethod("POST")
                .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                .addHeader("x-amz-acl", "bucket-owner-full-control")
                .addParameter("UserID", userId) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .setAutoDeleteFilesAfterSuccessfulUpload(false)
                .setUsesFixedLengthStreamingMode(true)
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(5)
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`
```

Console Error:
`I/System.out: [okhttp]:check permission begin! W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar I/System.out: [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin! W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils I/System.out: [okhttp]:check permission begin! W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar I/System.out: [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin! W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils I/System.out: [okhttp]:check permission begin! W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar I/System.out: [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin! W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils`

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer after lot of research it was my own mistake if it can save someone's day use this in your Manifest:

'android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"'

Comment: add  `<uses-permission android:name='android.requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"' />` in the manifest file.